# To expand partition volume of root

Tags: root, disk, volume-control, disk-management

I just installed on the whole disk of 1TB, the Ubuntu 14.04. 
However, the disk volume is being said that it is almost gone for `root` when installing all LaTeX and development packages to my system.

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf106a275

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048   17577983   17575936   8.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       17580030 1953523711 1935943682 923.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       17580032   23437311    5857280   2.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       23439360   39745535   16306176   7.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       39747584   40525823     778240   380M 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       40527872 1953523711 1912995840 912.2G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Output of `df`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        8518920  8502536         0 100% /
udev               10240        0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs             788972     9320    779652   2% /run
tmpfs            1972428    78084   1894344   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1972428        0   1972428   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7         368615     2231    342832   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5        2817056  1379092   1275148  52% /var
/dev/sda8      941357676 63231944 830284452   8% /home
tmpfs             394488        8    394480   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs             394488       32    394456   1% /run/user/1000
```

How can you increase dynamically the partition of root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can`t do this on a mounted partition, so you will need a live CD/USB.

you can get it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), then burn it to CD/USB and boot from it.

after you can use GParted tool included in live version of ubuntu and resize any needed partitions.

p.s. if ubuntu live will automatically mount partitions you want to resize you can unmount them via "right click" - "eject".

Comment: Is the installer Ubuntu/debian USB stick enough to prepare this? I have at the moment only Debian 8.1 USB installer.

Comment: looks like it doesn`t have GParted included, but possibly it contains some other partition manager which you could try.

Comment: Ok I am now in debian 8.1 live cd. Any guesses there?

Comment: Found some disc tool visual.

Comment: Ok tool Disks not for partitions, only for types.

Comment: well, if Debian 8.1 live doesn`t have any replacement for GParted - use ubuntu installer instead. You can revert your USB to Debian after if you need it.

Comment: I have just live cds on ubuntu, debian, xububtu and archlinux but none of them have gparted or similar.

Comment: Ok lets try ubuntu 8.1 live cd.

Comment: GParted is included in ubuntu live environment since 12.04 as far as i know(however it isn`t a part of installed system if you use same ISO as installator instead of live version). I provided a link where you can get ubuntu 14.04 ISO which i was using for similar task.

Comment: Instead of using live-cd boot-up of some OS, you could (and should) have more handy and all-purpose CD or USB-stick which is meant for example for these kind of usages. Here's a neat CD which is nice to have around: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ and to go even further, this is an all purpose boot CD with tons of features bundled into one: https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

Comment: @AhtiKomu Can you increase the root portion by it? The Ubuntu CD's Gparrted could not do that.

Comment: i used GParted successfully, the only issue i know of is partition being automatically mounted which can be fixed by right click -> eject.

my choice of bootable usb is personal, there are thousands bootable ISO`s to use, i just like to fix linux issues using linux tools, windows for windows, e.t.c.

and yeah, ultimatebootcd is a great tool to have.

Comment: @Masi Really? GParted should be able to do that. Be sure to have all the partitions on the disk unmounted. Before resizing sda1 partition, you should shrink sda8 (your /home) and then shrink sda2 (extended  partition holding the other partititions besides sda1) respectively, then move sda2 partition to make room for sda1 partition. Please consider giving a great deal of space for sda1. And be warned that the operation WILL take a long time since it has to physically move the data in the disk.

Comment: @ahtiKomu I cannot unmount in gparted so I think all are unmounted. I shrinked now sda2 so 500gb unallocated memory in sd2 but I do not find any button to move that 500gb to sd1. Any idea?

Comment: @ahti my /dev/sda1 is boot partition. Is this the reason why I cannot increase it?

Comment: @ahti I managed to unmount swap-linux so everything unmounted. I managed to move out free space from sda2 to general space but I still do not manage to increase sda1. Ideas?

Comment: @Masi You are not supposed to move anything from sd2 to sd1. You are supposed to move the _shrinked_ sd2 further away on the disk so that there is room for sd1 to expand (resize). So, now that you have unallocated space in sd2, rezise the sd2 partition to the minimum size so that it will have no unallocated space left (shrink), leaving unused space in the disk. Then move the sd2 partition to end of the disk. After that resize the sd1 partition to it's maximum size (expand) so that it uses the unused space left on the disk. That should do it.